# python dictionary sorting oddly (want non-alphabetical)

Tags: python, dictionary, key

so I am trying to send a packet with some keys that i have put into a dictionary. these need to be printed in a specific order, so I've tried to make a function to reorder them. I assume python is doing something to rearrange in the order I don't want, but i'm not sure why.

I'm currently using this function to try and achieve this.

```
def array_sort(array, sort): #yeah, it's array cuz i php like that.
    ordered = {}
    for i in range(0,len(sort)):
        if sort[i] in array:
            ordered[sort[i]] = array[sort[i]]
    keys = array.keys()
    return ordered 


order = "l5,l4,l3,l2,q,y,k,k3,d1,z,p,c,b,d3,dt,N,n,a,h,v".split(',')
keys = array_sort(infos, order)
```

for some reason this isn't working, `infos` is the list of keys in alphabetical order, i'm just not sure why the function is outputting the keys in an odd order. (a first, when 15 should be first :S)

If you know a better way to do this feel free to tell me, I just recently started on python, so I'm not that familiar.

EDIT:
I was able to print the keys in the correct order using this immediately after making the order dictionary. even if it was just output as a string the order would be preserved (for the time being) and you could .split() it again to get the dictionary in the correct order (i think).

```
for i in range(0, len(order)):
    if order[i] in infos:
        packet += order[i] + '="' + infos[order[i]] + '" '
```

Comment: Are you using the dictionary values at all? I don't see it. If not, just use a regular list instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since dictionaries in Python are unordered and all that you need is to output results ordered by the specified rule you can do something like this:

```
order = "l5,l4,l3,l2,q,y,k,k3,d1,z,p,c,b,d3,dt,N,n,a,h,v".split(',')

for key in order:
    print key, infos.get(key)#if infos is your dictionary
```

Or you can get/pass list instead of dict the following way:

```
print [(key, infos.get(key)) for key in order]
```

Answer (score 1):

Python dictionaries are not ordered containers.  Take a look at the [collections.OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead

Answer (score 0):

Python dictionaries order their keys based on its hash, which will make it seem random. I recommend using [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to get your keys in order.